# USB headset doesn't work unless I restart. Why?

Tags: usb, audio, headphones, headset

I have a Plantronics USB headset plugged into a ThinkPad running Windows 7. Every once in a while - in particular after my computer awakes from Sleep Mode - my USB headset stops working. In fact, all audio on my computer stops working -- nothing comes out of the computer speakers even when I unplug, and even my standard 1/8" audio headset does not work. Still, when I plug in or pull out the USB headset, the computer recognizes it (the volume bar pops up onscreen).

I suspect the problem has something to do with my soundcard or driver (which is updated), but I'm not sure what the solution is.

How can I fix this problem so I can listen to music without restarting?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the Device Manager and then in the section:

**Sound, video and game controllers**

There you'll just have to disable the device **(USB PNP SOUND)** *[or something similar]* and enable the device again and it will starts working without a restart.

This workaround is necessary because of faulty C-Media drivers.

Comment: This works also for nonusb Headset(s) at least for mine. Is updating drivers maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are there drivers for your Plantronics USB Headset?  What is sounds like is that the USB Headset isn't necessarily hot pluggable, and it's getting disconnected....  (Not the cable being removed, but there's a USB communication issue, and the headset is not recovering correctly).

I suspect that there might be a updated Plantronics driver, but I can't tell from the plantronics web site....  ( http://www.plantronics.com/us/support/software-downloads ).

Please note, this is an educated guess...  So I'm not sure that this will or won't help.  But it does fit your escription...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be drivers and settings as well!

- Check the that the drivers are installed and working correctly. Take a look at your device manager (right click *My Computer* icon and select *Properties* then should see either tabs to menu link that says *Device Manager*).
  See if there's anything wrong – indicated by an exclamation mark. If not, see if your device is listed and right click and select *Properties*. Check to see if there's a power tab that might solve your problem.
- If software came with the headset, go through that and see if there are any other settings that could help you bring it out of sleep mode or not to disconnect while being put into sleep mode.
- Does the port that the headset is plugged into do this without devices? Again, in *Device Manager* go to the USB controller, select the USB hub and see if power management is correct there too.
- Try resetting the hub from the *Advanced* tab and see if it comes back on and works.
- Try testing the sleep mode function with just selecting it from the Start menu and then use only the power button to turn back on the PC and see if that works!

Answer (score 0):

I tried DeviceManager settings - disable and enable...but no use... But Workaround, when you get away from your computer for more time, switch off bluetooth, THOUGH PC/LAPTOP goes to Sleep, as you login again - Switch ON bluetooth, it immediately recognizes your bluetooth devices...

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows 10 using a Plantronics headset. My issue was that when I disconnected the headset, my speakers didn't kick back in. Plugging in my 1/8" headphones didn't connect the audio back up either, but plugging the original headset back in got sound through it.

I fixed this by first disconnecting the headset and opening my Realtek HD audio manager. I plugged my normal headphones in, which then asked what device I'm using - headset was checked, so I unchecked this and selected headphones. This got things running as normal again.

Comment: I am unsure that this helps the original poster or someone else reading this question more than the other four answers.

Answer (score -1):

same issue. I fixed mine. I went to realtek HD audio's offcial website, downloaded the latest version driver, installed. Fixed.

Comment: How does this improve on the other answers already posted? It might better be posted as a comment.